# docker run throws: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I have image which I try to run with: `docker run -p 7111:7111 app/hello/hello:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT` but I receive: `sh: /app/bin/startApp.sh: No such file or directory`. When I check with `docker inspect image_id` then I can see:

```
"Entrypoint": [
     "sh",
     "/app/bin/startApp.sh"
 ],
```

Can I somehow get into image and check what exactly is inside?

Comment: depends on the image; if it's based off a standard linux distro and not from scratch you may be able to `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh ...` and it will give you a shell to take a look around.  Since it does seem to at least have a shell based on the error message this may work.

Comment: How did you create a Docker Image ? When you are creating docker image at that time you have to copy startApp.sh at "/app/bin/" location.

Comment: @KushPatel it's built with Dockerfile but yes, there is a possibility that there is a problem with coping this script to image but can I validate it in docker image?

Comment: @w08r, yes! `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh image_id` did the job, I have a shell! Thank you! Can you please change comment into answer as it's correct?

Comment: @KushPatel, indeed: `COPY /deployment/startApp.sh  /app/bin` was missing

Comment: (This class of debugging will be easier if you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in the Dockerfile...but without seeing a [mcve] it's hard to tell what might actually be wrong.)